# how to override "class=row" value using @media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

*div A


div B*

@media (max-width: 1340px) {

// i want to change the div B appearance independently. i don't want it to follow the row order at all when the width is 1330px or lower. instead, i would like, the divB to appear below div one not on the same row when the 1340px width is reached. //

before :          div A | div B.               [displaying side by side]

at width 1340px or lower  :

```
                     div A

                     -----        [displaying B below A]
                          
                     div B
```

is there any way to  achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@media screen and (max-width:1340px){
   .container{
      width:100vw;/width:100%;
}
  .container .a{
   width:100%;
}
  .container .b{
   width:100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:1329.98px){
   .container{
      width:100vw;/width:100%;
     display:inline-block;
}
  .container .a{
   width:50%;
}
  .container .b{
   width:50%;
}
}
```

if you are using bootstrap4 you have to remove row class by using jquery too. Then it will work like your desire.